# strings handling C linux and windows

Tags: c, windows, linux, string

I'm a newbie in C programming.
I have this issue that I don't understand. It seems that strings under windows are treated in a completely different way respect to linux, why?

Thant's my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h> // compare strings
void addextname(char *str1, char *str2, char *nome1){
    int i,j;
    i = 0;
    while (str1[i]!='.') {
        nome1[i] = str1[i];
        i++;
    }
    j = 0;
    while (str2[j]!='\0') {
        nome1[i] = str2[j];
        i++;
        j++;
    }
}

int main()
{
    char str1[9]="file.stl";
    char str2[9]="name.stl";
    int len1 = strlen(str1);
    int len2 = strlen(str2);
    char nome1[len1+len2+1];
    addextname(str1,str2,nome1);
    printf("%s  %s  %s\n",str1,str2,nome1);
    return 0;
}
```

My purpose is to read an input filename within its extension (.stl) and add some chars to it keeping that extension. Under linux I have no problem, under windows instead the output filenames are saved unproperly.
My compiling line is

```
gcc modstr.c -std=c99 -o strings
```

I really appreciate an answer to that!

Comment: @qiao which line did you edited, because the code seems like the previous

Comment: An indentation problem on a bracket which split the codeblock into two seperate ones. Just for better formatting :)

Comment: @qiao yeah! I thought it was something on my code but I figured later that the answer was below :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're not 0-terminating `nome1`. Try:

```
nome1[i] = 0; /* After the second while. */
```

Comment: ...and you should change `while (str1[i]!='.')` to `while (str1[i]!='.'&&str1[i]!='\0')` since otherwise addextname will crash when passed a filename without extension as first argument.

Comment: And you should start searching from the right, since a filename can contain more than one period.

Comment: @Axel, Ignacio Good call :-) Or maybe just use `strrchr` ?

Comment: @cnicutar thank you so much. It worked perfectly. Can you please tell me why I have to put a zero at the end instead of a terminate character '\0', which should be included in the second char.

Comment: @Nicholas If you watch closely the second while doesn't actually store the last `\0`.

Comment: @cnicutar looking deeply you are right because the while loop stops when it finds the end of char without writing it! Thank you so much again.

Answer (score 0):

Your have created the array `nome1` but have not furnished it with anything. Is it psychic?

Comment: I've just initialized nome1 memory address and in the addextname I "fill" that memory address. Am I right?